# Adding Position: fixed; ruins the header

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

the whole banner messes up and ends with a piece of the code.
I've been experimenting on popular websites, and when this one came along I've been having a lot of trouble.

How do I make it so the `position: fixed;` doesn't ruin it?

Comment: use Jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ and do a demo -- if you use special  plugins you can get the links  from here https://cdnjs.com/ and in fiddle expand (External Resources) on the lest side and past in the link(s)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you position all element to fixed?

Comment: Can you share a demo link?

Answer (score 0):

Wooahh you've added position fixed onto every single element of the page with this line:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

You should only add position fixed to the element you want to be fixed. If its the top nav then something like this.

```
nav#top {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I did that and nothing happened. just sort of lagged out the button:hover stuff